# Change elements on the UI thread with data received in onEvent using AndroidAsync's SocketIOClient

Tags: websocket, android, androidasync-koush

I can see emitted messages from the server in the Android app's console log using `System.out`.  How do I actually use this new data to change things in my UI though?

I have tried `setText` on a `TextView` that I got a handle to in `onCreate`.  No error is thrown but nothing actually happens.

I also tried making a `Toast` but I get an error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is saying that you are trying to change the UI(Toast) from a different thread.. if you want to change the UI from a different thread you must call the UI/Main thread first and put it there..

**Sample::**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Do the changing of UI here
                        }
                 });
```